# jquery .change() not working when my cart input fields are update

Tags: jquery

I have a small script that should update the cart count on my page if a product is added or subtracted. This does not seem to be working when i add a cart item and the quantity filed is changed but it does if i refresh the page:

```
(function($){
    jQuery(".hikashop_cart_module input.hikashop_product_quantity_field").change(function(){
        var sum = 0;
        $(".hikashop_cart_module input.hikashop_product_quantity_field").each(function(){
            sum += +$(this).val();
        }).change();
        $("#total").text(sum);  
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: `change` is triggered when you leave the input field. Also, you added the `.change()` (trigger) to the `.each`, not to the event handler. Is that what needs to happen?

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors in your code. Compare with this one:

```
(function($){
    // if you load your elements dynamically you need to use delegated events
    $(document).on('change', '.hikashop_cart_module input.hikashop_product_quantity_field', function(){
        var sum = 0;
        $(this).each(function(){
            sum += +$(this).val();
        });
        $("#total").text(sum);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: i think the problem is that change() is fired when a user exits an input field, where in my case the user is simply using an add to cart button and the cart input fields are changed by an ajax script embedded in the shopping cart component. any suggestions on how to handle this?

Comment: Then you need to use a delegated event, check [this article](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in your selectors. You should use this:

```
(function($){
    jQuery(".hikashop_cart_module.input.hikashop_product_quantity_field").change(function(){
        var sum = 0;
        $(".hikashop_cart_module.input.hikashop_product_quantity_field").each(function(){
            sum += +$(this).val();
        })
        $("#total").text(sum);  
    });
})(jQuery);
```

There's also an issue with the `each` loop following by the `.change()` event handler. It was creating an infinite loop of firing the event. I've made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zmt8L9uy/) so you can see the working version in action!